# Views Slideshow Output different in IE vs Firefox/Chrome/Safari

Tags: 7, views

A site I'm working on is using Views and the Views Slideshow plugin to generate a tabbed panel on the site. We modified the output of the plugin to display link names instead of IDs, which worked great. The view set the link back to the node.

We modified the view itself to instead use a link that the user specifies on the node instead of linking back directly to the node itself. Cleared the cache and FF works fine. When I test in IE, it doesn't link anywhere (the anchor's href is actually empty).

I've got all the caching on Drupal turned off, deleted the cache in IE, rebooted... the module itself seems to be outputting different HTML based upon the browser. Any ideas on where to start looking? I'm digging through the module itself right now but I'm not seeing anything that stands out.

**Update**

What ended up happening was a module (not the one I was working on) was detecting IE and including javascript that was for IE only. This extra javascript ran before mine and mangled some of the tags I needed to work with.

Answer (score 2):

When browsers create different markup, the problem is most likely an error in the HTML, where IE is particulary bad at making broken HTML work.

Try comparing the actual source code for the page to see if it is the same.

If even the source is different it's most likely an issue with a reverse proxy or similar. Some are known to cause problems with IE with certain configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, the answer is in the HTML source of the page (View Page Source). Regardless of the browser, they are all working with the same base HTML code which they then attempt to correct if they're not able to interpret correctly. FireFox tends to be more forgiving but the fact that it's not working in IE suggests that you have some type of typo.

Look at the HTML source around where the problem links are via "How do I view the source code of a web page?" -> http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000746.htm. Silly things like typos or missing quotations can often be the root of the issue.

Remember, the problem is in *your* source not in the specific browser.

Comment: If the problem page is viewable to the public perhaps point us to the issue so we do a quick review of the source.